# How to edit Engine Compute API quota?

Tags: google-compute-engine, quota

We're trying to edit a **Compute Engine API** quota, but it's returning an error. We contacted the sales team and they advised us to open a case in this forum. In this case, we have a limit of 8 and we want to raise the new limit to 12.

Comment: More details are required. What is the error message? Which Compute Engine API is exceeding quota. Review this list of API quotas to figure out which one: https://cloud.google.com/compute/api-quota#api-rate-limits